# Is there something like List<T>.First in Java?

Tags: java

In C#, I can get a specific element in a List with the following:

```
Student data = lstStrings.First(s => s.ID == id);
```

Where Student is my own type / class.

How do I do this in Java? I haven't worked with List in Java yet and couldn't find anything helpful on the internet. I only found questions about ArrayList in Java, which is not what I am looking for.

Please forgive me, if this question already exists. Thanks for your help.